# Making Kafka ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer Work as a Batch

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

In my application, I created my own custom listener in order to not use the @KafkaListener annotation. I configured to listen the messages in a record to record bases. That is working. Now I want to transform my custom listener to listen to messages in a batch. Should I just configure the ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG to the amount of message I want to process per poll? I would also change my AckMode to BATCH. Is this all I need to do?

I know that ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory has the property "setBatchListener(true)", but as far as I understand the Kafka documentation, this type of factory configuration is only utilized with the @KafkaListener annotation.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the max poll records is a limit, not a hard-number; you might still need to increase the poll timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your listener to implement `BatchMessageListener` or one of its sub-interfaces instead. The container will automatically detect its type.

See [Message Listeners](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.2/reference/html/#message-listeners).

The `@KafkaListener` code uses the factory flag to determine which type of listener adapter to create.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you @GaryRussell, that is what I am doing. Is there any other way to set the poll size other than ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG ?

Comment: That is a MAX; you will get UP TO that number of records; there is no `MIN_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG` - you can only control the minimum approximately, using [`fetch.min.bytes`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#fetch.min.bytes) and [`fetch.max.wait.ms`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#fetch.max.wait.ms).